# MassTransit Consuming Raw Json from an existing SQS queue

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I have an app that is consuming raw json from a pre-existing SQS queue for interoperability with another system.  We're using the Amazon Sqs client (.Net Sdk). I'd like to switch this to have a MassTransit consumer pull the raw json.

I've watched the video that shows how to Bind to a RabbitMQ queue to consume messages without MT wrappers, but I can't see how to subscribe the consumer to SQS manually.

There is no sns topic, just the sqs queue.

IAmazonSqsReceiveEndpointConfigurator only has Subscribe methods that refer to topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consuming raw JSON from an SQS with MassTransit is easy.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<SomeConsumer>();

    x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(...);

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("existing-sqs-queue", e =>
        {
            e.UseRawJsonSerializer(isDefault: true);

            e.ConfigureConsumer<SomeConsumer>();
        });
    });    
});
```

Any message on the queue will be delivered to the consumer.

Comment: In this case, what is the Generic Type for consumer `string` or `object` ? 
I refer to the generic type in this side: IConsumer<T>